# There is a bug in this code but I cannot find it

Tags: c, debugging

I'm preparing for an interview and came across a practice question that I could not figure out. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p,*q;
    p=(char *)malloc(25);
    q=(char *) malloc(25);
    strcpy(p,"amazon" );
    strcpy(q,"hyd");
    strcat(p,q);
    printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

I compiled it and executed it, but it worked just fine. There is a problem with the code, which makes me suspect it has something to do with uninitialized variables. The output is amazonhyd like it should be. Could someone let me know what I'm missing?

edit: This is a practice interview question, and the question is asking what is wrong with in this code.

Comment: what makes you think that "There is a problem with the code" ?

Comment: You've omitted `#include <stdlib.h>` so the compiler has to work in C90 mode and assumes `malloc()` returns an `int`, but if you're on a 64-bit system, the value it returns is not the same size as an `int`, so you run into all sorts of problems.  Less seriously, you omitted `#include <string.h>` too.  However, the assumptions made by C90 mode are unlikely to affect the operation of the string functions.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Besides the header-file problem, the question might be about memory leaks. Without more context about the code and the interview question it's really hard to tell what is the expected answer.

Comment: For style reasons I would ask for functions to have prototypes even in their definitions, but that's not a "problem".

Comment: Oh, and since this is C you really should use `int main(void)` to say that `main` doesn't take any arguments. Also note that not having an explicit `return` statement can lead to errors on older compilers (that's not up to date with newer standards of C).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for showing me the link, it was useful on reviewing pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are missing includes.

The `malloc` function requires stdlib.h, while `strcpy` and `strcat` require string.h.  Without them, these functions are assumed to return in `int`.

This is particularly problematic for `malloc` if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void *)`.  Because the implied definition does not match the actual definition, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  One of the ways for undefined behavior to manifest itself is that the program appears to work properly.  However, this behavior is not guaranteed.

For the program to be conforming, add the following at the top.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Also, this program allocates memory but does not `free` it.  Each call to `malloc` should have a corresponding call to `free`.  Otherwise, you have a memory leak.

Add the following after the call to `printf` to patch the memory leak.

```
free(p);
free(q);
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about headers and memory leaks! While I do not have the answer for this practice question, your answer is clear and constructive.